# UnsupportedOperationException: Exceeded maximum number of wifi locks

Tags: java, android

I'm using a open source package 
https://github.com/andriydruk/RxDNSSD/ and I'm getting this exception but dunno how to fix it or why it happened (I can fork the project if someone can tell me why that exception triggered)

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Exceeded maximum number of wifi locks
at android.net.wifi.WifiManager$MulticastLock.acquire(WifiManager.java:4911)
at com.github.druk.dnssd.DNSSD.onServiceStarting(DNSSD.java:569)
at com.github.druk.dnssd.DNSSDBindable.onServiceStarting(DNSSDBindable.java:38)
at com.github.druk.dnssd.DNSSD.queryRecord(DNSSD.java:412)
at com.github.druk.dnssd.DNSSD.queryRecord(DNSSD.java:408)
at com.example.sweeprapitest.Discovery.BonjourDiscovery.startQueryRecords(BonjourDiscovery.java:255)
at com.example.sweeprapitest.Discovery.BonjourDiscovery.access$300(BonjourDiscovery.java:28)
at com.example.sweeprapitest.Discovery.BonjourDiscovery$3.serviceResolved(BonjourDiscovery.java:205)
at com.github.druk.dnssd.DNSSD$2.lambda$serviceResolved$0(DNSSD.java:240)
at com.github.druk.dnssd.-$$Lambda$DNSSD$2$0OhPKoqzFsN_3_yfNshD9HEzVL4.run
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```